# SQL ONLY read file from drive into a byte array

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way that SQL Server can read from a file on a drive and convert it into a byte array?  I have just installed 2017 which has a function to convert my sql query results to a JSON string and wanted to know if SQL Server can perform this byte array so I do not have to do it in VB..  If it is not possible I can do it in VB..

Thanks in advance..

Derek.

Comment: "Is there a way that SQL Server can read from a file on a drive" this is a bad idea and requires OS privileges you don't want to give. You should do this outside SQL Server. There might be some exceptions though, but you don't want to allow this kind of procedures for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you..  was just reading about the privileges.  You basically have to open up SQL allow drive permissions and that can lead to all sorts of issues..  I think VB will be the way..  Cheers for the advice..